# MySQL Workbench 6.3.7 crashes on query with Windows 10 Home

Tags: mysql, windows-10, mysql-workbench, ntdll

I have this recurring issue of MySQL Workbench (v6.3.7) query crashing on execution. The OS is Windows 10 Home, and the application event log shows the following message pointing to `faulting module` as `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll`:

```
Faulting application name: MySQLWorkbench.exe, version: 6.3.7.0, time stamp: 0x5758217b
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x578997b2
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000f73e3
Faulting process ID: 0x15b4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d204f3e36c6cb2
Faulting application path: C:\Devtools\MySQL\MySQLWorkbench6.3CE\MySQLWorkbench.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report ID: 58851aa0-0502-4670-a1bb-10a00f8afcc6
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: I suspect you are missing some required prerequisites, such as MSVC 2013. This happens when installing via the Zip file (instead of a MSI) as it appears you've done. Consider installing Workbench via MySQL Installer as it checks for such things.

Comment: Thanks @philipOlson, but I used the msi installer though not sure if msvc 2013 was exclusively installed. Anyway I'll try your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue. Found a reference in MySQL bugs recommending reverting to 6.3.6 511, which seems to have resolved the issue for me.